# how to redirect to requested url after login

Tags: php, codeigniter

My url is http://betaonetesting.com/watch_new/seller/accept_bids/98
I put vatidation on this like my controller is

```
class Seller extends CI_Controller { 


function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
     $this->check_isvalidated();

}
    private function check_isvalidated()
{
    if(! $this->session->userdata('valid')){
        redirect(base_url().'User/seller_login');
    }

}
}
```

when i request for http://betaonetesting.com/watch_new/seller/accept_bids/98 it takes me to User/seller_login but after login it takes me to home page not requested url as http://betaonetesting.com/watch_new/seller/accept_bids/98

How to do this... pls help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to store the previous or referral url in session.
then redirect the session url.

```
if(! $this->session->userdata('valid')){
    $this->session->set_userdata('rurl', current_url());
    redirect(base_url().'User/seller_login');
}


function login()
{
    redirect($this->session->userdata('rurl'));
}
```

or try below one.

```
redirect($this->agent->referrer());
```

Thanks,